# Update link in item?

Tags: sitecore

I have the following small script

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
            foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item child in item.Children)
            {
                foreach (ItemLink link in child.Links.GetAllLinks())
                {
                    Item itm = link.GetTargetItem();
                    if (itm != null) {
                        Response.Write(link.TargetPath + " (" + itm.Paths.IsMediaItem + ", " + itm.ID + ")" + "<br/>");
                    } else
                    {
                        Response.Write("<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>NULL ITEM ("+ link.TargetPath + ")</span><br/>");
                    }
                }           

                if (item.Paths.ContentPath.Split("/".ToCharArray()).Length <= 10)
                    RecurseLinks(child, reset);
            }
    }
```

This loops through all items (and children) from a specified startpath and gets all links defined in the items.

Some of the links i need to update, as some of them are currently defined with a absolute path, and not the  ID of the item that it is linked to (media or content item).

How would i achive this in the mentioned script?

Comment: I dont understand why you are using SecurityDisabler, unless the content is protected or you are trying to modify the content items in sitecore. Also, from you question it is not clear what you are trying to achieve: rewrite sitecore item urls in database or render absolute path of items?

Comment: @xoail I am using the SecurityDisabler because i want to modify the content - just have not figured out how, yet :-) The script mentioned lists all links within my items. It is a Sitecore 6.5 solution, so pr default the links will be listed with the GUID. But as some of the content is imported from another solution, some of the links, are linkin directly to the file in the media library. Something like "~/media/my folder/my pdf file.pdf.ashx". Those i want to change, so they link to the GUID instead (and then i can control how it is displayed to the user via the web.config setting).

Comment: I doubt that it will work but have you tried calling Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabaseHelper.UpdateLink(child); for each child?

Comment: @ChristianHagelid Did not know that one. But cant find any good documentation on what it actually does?

Comment: I found it when looking through the Kernel dll in ILSpy. Was a little hard to see what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

The "rebuild link database" action should work.
The empty ID's are probably caused by broken links (target items not found in the database at the time of updating the links).
So rebuilding the links via the control panel, or in your code (see `LinkDatabaseHelper`) should work.

Comment: The problem is that some links are "hardcoded" in the rich text editor. I want to change these to link to the GUID's of the item instead of the absolute link.